# Can not record browser action in jmeter

Tags: proxy, server, jmeter

I am using apache-jmeter-2.6. I want to record browser action using HTTP Proxy Server. But The actions are not recording.

I have defined HTTP Request Defaults under Thread Group,I have given value for the server name that looks like this:

http://www.xxxxx.com:81/

And I left the Port Number field empty as it is given with the Server Name.

In HTTP Proxy Server under workbench, I have given the Port value:81 and added ".*.html" in URL Patterns to include.

I have set the proxy server setting in firefox browser with Port:81 and Http Proxy: www.xxxxx.com

Now when I start the proxy server in jmeter and do different actions in my browser, i get nothing in my listener which is 'View Result Tree'.

I have searched for the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file in different directories of my pc so that I can install it in my browser but did not find it anywhere, seems it is not created.

I have also deleted proxyserver.jks and then tried everything again, but no success.

What am i doing wrong here? How do i fix this?

My java version is 1.8.0_77.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all  I recommend you to upgrade your JMeter version.JMeter 2.13 version is available.The performance of JMeter is being constantly improved, so users are highly encouraged to use the most up to date version. 
Ensure you always read changes list to be aware of new improvements and components. You should absolutely avoid using versions that are older than 3 versions before the last one.

> **Here is the step by step process of recording browsers action**.

**Step1:** Open your **Firefox browser** and from **Network Connection** settings configure the proxy server as **HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1, Port: 8888**

[image: Fireefox configuration for Proxy setting]

**Step2:** Run your Jmeter.bat file and open **Templates** under **File** dropdown list and click **"Create"**.

[image]

**Step3:** Expand **Work Bench** and select **"HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder"**. And click **"Start"** at the bottom of the page.You will have two pop up to **Allow Firewall and Temporary Root CA Certification Installation**.Allow all those and now go to your browser and do your browser activity.When its done **"Stop"** the
**HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder**.

**Step4:** After this you will get the recorder script in JMeter with all your activity in the browser.It will automatically update under **Thread Group**.This script will contain all your page requests during browsing activity. Sample script after recording is shown below.

[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have solved my problem. But I am still using jmeter 2.6 because I am facing problem with ApacheJMeter.jar file in the latest versions. It is giving errorlevel 1 and 2. I have tried to solve this problem but nothing worked, so I went back to jmeter 2.6.  I just used the ip and port number you have suggested, and that has solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you tell me why you have suggested to use port 8888,it will be helpful for me.

Comment: It's the default port assigned to JMeter Proxy settings.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: It's the default port assigned to JMeter Proxy settings. Please go through the link below as I can't attach any image file here!!

http://screencast.com/t/MvXIxbJ0R 

One more thing, you can use the latest JMeter Version 2.13 but make sure that in you Apache JMeter **lib** directory, there are three jar files named **"httpclient-4.5.jar", "httpcore-4.4.1.jar" , "httpmime-4.5.jar"**.


 **These  jar files should not be duplicate!!!** 

It is suggested that always use latest version of JMeter when performing Load Tests.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need latest JMeter first! Download [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).
2. Check [this tutorial](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) on recording.
3. `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` can be found in `JMETER_HOME/bin` folder.