# Are complex test scenarios with JMeter possible?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I need to run performance tests on a web application and was wondering if the following can be accomplished with Apache JMeter.

I need to simulate approximately 300 users accessing an application over a set time frame (e.g. 300 users over 10 minutes) and doing some actions, for example:

- Logging in
- Navigating to different pages
- Inputting data
- Submitting forms

I'm quite new to JMeter and performance testing in general and was wondering if this is possible? Otherwise are there any better (free) alternatives?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible using JMeter.

I would recommend using JMeter/ Blazemeter [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi). BlazeMeter's Chrome extension let you test your application without prior scripting knowledge. It is very easy to create a test with BlazeMeter's Google Chrome extension. Here are some blogs that will help or guide you to use [Chrome extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) and [forth](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732849-Chrome-Extension-Record).

There is another option, that is JMeter build in [Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Go through This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914303/can-not-record-browser-action-in-jmeter/36922691#36922691) for further detail.

Follow any one of the two procedures to record your scenario and then customize the imported script according to your requirement.

1. First, record your scenario using Chrome Extension.
2. Import the generated .jmx file to your Jmeter.
3. Configure the Test plan according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what JMeter is designed for.

For the basics following documentation chapters are very useful:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#building)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

When it comes to the load distribution just use separate [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent different groups of virtual users (like some users are logging in, another are navigating pages, etc.). If you have only one group of virtual users and several actions to simulate you can go for [Throughput Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Comment: Thank you, although I am having trouble due to the fact that the application does not contain any static links. I'm new to JMeter so I'm not sure if this is a problem with my understanding of the application or something that limits JMeter.