# Proxy is not working in windows 10

Tags: proxy, jmeter, ip, capture

I want to record a jmeter(v-3.2 r1790748) script and i have setup proxy in my mozilla browser (v-55.0). defined ip 127.0.0.1 and port 8080 but when ever i tried to access the website it shows the error, "The proxy server is refusing connections". Please help to get out of this issue

Comment: This seems to be a very trivial problem. What have you checked already?

Comment: Did you start JMeter recorder before accessing site? Did you specify the same details in JMeter recorder?

Comment: did all the possible ways, install cc proxy to fix this issue, remove entries from registry. But nothing worked

Comment: Can you show in you question (not in comment) your Test script recorder configuration ? and Browser configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's Global Setting for Proxy port is defined as `8888`

So, I would suggest you change the port 8080 to 8888 in the Mozilla browser's proxy setup configuration.

Also, could follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914303/can-not-record-browser-action-in-jmeter/36922691#36922691).